# uilabel text with new line only when required

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilabel

this is what i am using:

it works if address, city, zip.....length >0.(these field may grow in future)

```
self.addressInfoLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%@\n%@\n%@", address, city, zip, state, country];(numberofline == 0)
```

but if any of them length =0 then i got unnecessary new line.
i am working on manually preparing(appending \n).if there are more  and more fields then doing it manuallt is really hard.
Is there any other proper way.Am i doing it right.

Thanks

Comment: answer of @Avt is perfect it will work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following code. It creates array of your strings, removes empty strings and then concatenates them with `componentsJoinedByString` :

```
NSArray *strings = @[address, city, zip, state, country];
strings = [strings filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
NSString *resultString = [strings componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join an array of objects into a string with a separator:

```
NSArray *props = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: address, city, state, nil];
NSString *joinedString = [props componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

and you will get:

```
"6th avenue\nAtlanta\nGeorgia"
```

If you don't know the amount of properties, use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray` and add your properties at runtime.

Comment: if `city.length == 0`, Again he will get a newLinesapce.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, it not optimal but it can resolve youy issue

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"address", @"", @"state", nil];
NSString *addressInfo = @"";
for (NSString *str in arr) {
    if (str.length > 0) {
       addressInfo = [addressInfo stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n%@", str]];
    }
}
if (addressInfo && ![@"" isEqualToString:addressInfo])
    addressInfo = [addressInfo substringFromIndex:1];
NSLog(@"address Info = %@", addressInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once,

```
NSMutableString *joinedString=[NSMutableString string];
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: address, city, state, nil];
for(NSString *str in arr)
{
    if([str length]>0) [joinedString appendFormat:@"\n%@", str];
}

NSString *resultString=[joinedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"%@", resultString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Lbl.numberOfLines=0;
Lbl.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
```